# Trap workbooks events from Excel add-in

Tags: excel, vba

I try to create an add-in, mostly as a POC, but it does not work. What am I missing ?
I just want the add-in to debug.print the name of the workbook when it is activated.
The class self instantiating, thanks to the PredeclaredId attribute set to True (the part before `Option Explicit` only works if you **IMPORT** the class, it cannot be typed in the VBE).
Here is the class module:

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = 0
END
Attribute VB_Name = "clsWb"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents myApp As Application
Attribute myApp.VB_VarHelpID = -1

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set myApp = Application
End Sub

Private Sub myApp_WorkbookActivate(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    Debug.Print Now, Wb.Name
End Sub
```

Comment: How/where do  you refer to the class to instantiate it? It doesn't happen otherwise.

Comment: I thought the VB_PredeclaredId attribute would do that magic. But I'll try to try to instantiate it on add-in open, and see what that gives. Thx

Comment: No, all that means is that you don't have to create a new instance of the class *when using it in your code*. It doesn't make it magically create an instance of itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No other class is needed to accomplish what you want. Please, try proceeding in the next way:

Copy the next code in add-in `ThisWorkbook` code module:

```
Public WithEvents myApp As Application

Sub ActivateMyAppH()
    Set myApp = Application
End Sub

Sub InAactivateMyAppH()
    Set myApp = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub myApp_WorkbookActivate(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    Debug.Print Now, Wb.Name
End Sub
```

(Firstly, manually) run `ActivateMyAppH` and play with activating documents.

After seeing it working, place a call in the add-in `Workbook_Open` event:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   ActivateMyAppH
   'whatever necessary, if the event is already used for something else
End Sub
```

To be on the safe side, take care to inactivate the event:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
   InAactivateMyAppH
End Sub
```

Comment: This works great thanks! BTW ThisWorkbook _IS_ a class module, but indeed, no need to create another one.

Comment: @Patrick Honorez Of course it is. I wanted suggesting that no **other** class (than existing) should be necessary... In fact, it is good to clarify the answer, from this point of view. I will edit the answer and correct the meaning in discussion. Glad I could help!